# jQuery cycle how to resume a paused cycle when clicking on pager

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have a jquery cycle running with a pager. It automatically cycles, and it has pager buttons to manually control the cycle, after using the pager buttons it resumes automatic advance. Now I also built an external button to pause the cycle. But after the cycle is paused using this button I want it to resume cycling when a pager button is clicked... but that is what it doesn't do.

Tips or tricks anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wire an event to your pager to resume the cycle:

```
$('#pager li').click(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle('resume');
});​
```

Here is a full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/fg6d4/2/

Update per comment:

Alternatively you could bind on mouseleave and click and it should fix the hover issue too:

```
$('#pager li').on("mouseleave click",function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle('resume');
});​
```

Comment: Thanx, I had that. But just found out that when cycle option: pauseOnPagerHover: 1 is set this doesn't work. It's a minor thing for me to ditch the pause on page hover for this one. So now it works with this code.

Comment: I updated the answer.. If you were having problems resuming with the pause on page hover you should be able to fix that as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/fg6d4/2/